# [1: not found (условия в bash)

Tags: bash, unix, sh

Вот скрипт:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in  1 2 4 8
do

if [$i = 1 ]
then
    make
    fakeroot time make -j  --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers 
exit
else
    make
fakeroot time make -j $i  --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers 
fi;
done
```

а вот что он выдает...

```
5: ./start.sh: [1: not found
```

тоесть ругается конкретно на if - как правильно написать?

Comment: пробел добавьте: `if [ $i = 1 ]`. Не знаю правильна ли конструкция `$i = 1`, но квадратные скобочки должны быть пробелом отделены

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужен пробел после `[`.

Дело в том, что после `if` должно стоять истина или ложь. Поэтому `[` - это команда (как и любая команда, она возвращает результат своего выполнения), которой передаются параметры вплоть до конца строки или до `;`. В вашем случае bash ругается на то, что не нашел команды `[1`.